# What does the halfdelay function in curses do?

Tags: c, curses

I am trying to make sense of the following C program :

```
#include <curses.h> 

int main() {
    int i; 
    initscr(); 
    halfdelay(5);
    for (i=0; i < 5; i++) 
        getch(); 
    endwin();
}
```

But I cannot make sense of it. I understand `initscr()` initialising the current screen, and that `getch()` is waiting for user input to unlock the current terminal, but what is the loop and `halfdelay()` accomplishing here ?

Comment: Have you tried a google search? There are lots of results available....!

Comment: Yes. I have tried a google search.

Comment: It's not serious enough to "flag" but, respectfully, I'd like to mark Nick's post as not adding anything useful. I googled "curses.halfdelay" and this page was the topmost find! Look forward, folks. Everything's somewhere on Google!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`halfdelay(n);` sets an input mode where the `getch` function waits `n` tenths of a second (in your example program, half a second) for the user to type something. `getch` returns the keypress, unless the timer elapses, in which case it returns `ERR`. This mode can be turned off again with `cbreak()` or `nocbreak()`.

This can be used in code that, e.g., asks the user for confirmation but defaults to some value if they don't respond within a certain time frame.

Answer (score 0):

halfdelay is used to disable buffering of chars with 50 sec check for user inactivity.

this sample reads 5 chars from user input. if user is inactive for 0.5 seconds then getch returns ERR with errno set to EINTR.

see details [there](http://linux.die.net/man/3/halfdelay) and [there](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getch)

Comment: Half a second, not 50 seconds.

Comment: @FredFoo I edited the answer to have the correct value.